# U matrix in Singular value decompositon.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

I know that the Singular Value Decomposition of a matrix $X$ is given by:

$X = U\Sigma V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ matrices are column orthonormal and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal square matrix containing singular values.

Does $U$ contain the eigenvectors of $XX^T$? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, $U$ contains the eigenvectors of $XX^T$. The reason for this can be found in most proofs of the SVD, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVD is formed from the covariance matrices $X^{T}X$ and $XX^{T}$. you can show this.

$$ XX^{T}  = (U \Sigma V^{T}) (U \Sigma V^{T})^{T} \tag{1}   $$
$$ XX^{T}  = U \Sigma V^{T} V \Sigma^{T} U^{T} \tag{2}   $$

we know that $VV^{T} = V^{T}V = I$
$$ XX^{T}  = U \Sigma \Sigma^{T} U^{T} \tag{3}   $$

also $ \Sigma^{T} \Sigma  = \Sigma \Sigma^{T} = \Lambda$
$$ XX^{T}  = U \Lambda  U^{T} \tag{4}   $$
$U $ are **left singular vectors**.
Note that they are eigenvectors of the covariance matrix $XX^{T}$
similarly

$$ X^{T}X  = (U \Sigma V^{T})^{T} (U \Sigma V^{T}) \tag{5}   $$
$$ X^{T}X  = V \Sigma^{T} U^{T} U \Sigma V^{T} \tag{6}   $$
$ U^{T}U = UU^{T} = I $
$$ X^{T}X  = V \Sigma^{T} \Sigma V^{T} \tag{7}   $$
$$ X^{T}X  = V \Lambda V^{T} \tag{8}   $$

$V $ are **right singular vectors**.
They are eigenvectors $X^{T}X$ like above

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to evaluate $XX^T=U\Sigma V^TV\Sigma U^T=U\Sigma^2U^T=U\Sigma^2U^{-1}.$

Then the Eigenvalues of $XX^T$ are the squares of the singular values and its Eigenvectors indeed form $U$.